# Delete currently logged user when the session is expired for that user

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql, session

I have maintained sessions for users logs in my webApp, 1 for customer and another for employee.

Once the customer gets logged in I am storing his ID in a table called `current_users`

```
pg_query($con,"insert into current_users values ('".$row2['id']."','','','')");
```

While logging out, the user is deleted from current_users

```
if(pg_query($con,"delete from current_users where cid='$id'")){
  session_destroy();
  header('Location:index.php');
  }
```

Now the problem is, this works fine when the user logs out clicking on `logout` button, but what if the user just closes the site?, or what if the session is expired but the user is still there in `current_users`?.

Is there a way to log out customer when the session gets expired?(like just redirecting to logout.php would be enough for me), or is there a way to know if the session got expired while the user is not on website (he just closed it without logout).

Note:- I am using session in php apache server.

Comment: Store a session expiration in the current_users table and periodically prune users whose expiration has past.

Comment: @TheGentleman in that way I need more dynamic site and would be complex as well, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: why not sockets in your site to monitor active users without depending on session  . more faster, and reliable and accurate .